# Get info from json

Tags: json, node.js

My node application is generation an error in format:

```
{ [Error: Username already exists]
  index: 0,
  instance:
   { username: [Getter/Setter],
     name: [Getter/Setter],
     email: [Getter/Setter],
     password: [Getter/Setter],
     birthday: [Getter/Setter],
     gender: [Getter/Setter],
     join_date: [Getter/Setter],
     id: [Getter/Setter] } }
```

How can i access the "Username already exists" text? The output above its a console.log() of the object.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its an express.js Error object, to retrieve the message i need to user error.message